# Can a table view have it's own distinct header and footer?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When I have a table view with some sections which have their own headers and footers, could that table view also have it's very own header and footer with a customized look/content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. See UITableView's `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` properties.